# Ĉu Zamenhof ne intencis Esperanton por instruado?

Tags: teaching

Kial Zamenhof neniam uzis (aplikis) la radikojn *instru* kaj *lern* rilate Esperanton, dum *kompren* kaj (mem)*lern* estis uzitaj de li pri Esperanto eĉ 263 fojojn?

Comment: "Zamenhof neniam uzis..." - Kial vi pensas tion?

Comment: "Estas vero, ke homoj instruitaj povas ellerni Esperanton pli rapide, ol homoj neinstruitaj, sed ankaŭ la lastaj ellernas ĝin treege kaj mireginde facile, ĉar por la ellernado de la lingvo Esperanto de la lernanto estas postulataj neniaj antaŭaj scioj." - Zamenhof

Answer (score 2):

Efektive, Zamenhof ja diris:

> Estas vero, ke homoj instruitaj povas ellerni Esperanton pli rapide, ol homoj neinstruitaj, sed ankaŭ la lastaj ellernas ĝin treege kaj mireginde facile, ĉar por la ellernado de la lingvo Esperanto de la lernanto estas postulataj neniaj antaŭaj scioj.